# CMD Findstr with ping

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, ping, findstr

I am writting a batch file that pings a website, for example:

```
Pinging youtube.com [173.194.70.91] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 173.194.70.91: bytes=32 time=187ms TTL=44

Ping statistics for 173.194.70.91:
    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 187ms, Maximum = 187ms, Average = 187ms
```

and my program must copy just the IP address and save it into a text file.

So it pings into a text file

```
ping youtube.com >> file.txt
```

Now I use the `findstr` command to find the IP address. And that's fine if I use this:

```
ping youtube.com -n 1 >nul >>C:\Users\Adrian\Desktop\IP.txt
findstr /i "Reply from 173.194.70.93: bytes=32 time=188ms TTL=43 C:\IP.txt

IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
  echo You are winning
) else (
  echo You are losing
)
pause
```

Now it says I'm winning and thats a good thing but my program must find the IP address without knowing it. So the `findstr` command must know to get the IP address in between here...

```
"Reply from 173.194.70.91: bytes=32 time=187ms TTL=44"
```

so it must `findstr` the IP from that string. But I have been Googling and found nothing.

Comment: Do you want the IP address in any case, or just when you receive a response from the host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off &setlocal 
for /f "tokens=2delims=[]" %%i in ('ping -n 1 youtube.com^|find "["') do set "ip=%%i"
echo.%ip%>>file.txt
endlocal
```

Comment: Thanks but could you please explain the for /f and the tokens to me :), Yes I have come accross it and understand it a little

Comment: The find command catches the output line from `ping` with the `[` character inside. Tokens are on this line between delimiters. Token 1 is `Pinging youtube.com` and token 2 the IP address (between `[` and `]`).

Answer (score 0):

If PowerShell is acceptable then you could try:

```
[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses("youtube.com") | foreach {echo $_.IPAddressToString }
```

Comment: Another question... Could you tell me wher firefox, google chrome, internet explorer store the browing history file?

Comment: That's definitely a question worth creating a new thread for, but through some Googling there are tools like History Export that can export browsing history from web browsers.

Comment: No because it's part of my program to delete browsing history (cmd)